# Expected rel[loc,loc] (...), but got rel[loc,loc], what does rel[loc,loc](...) mean?

Tags: rascal

I just tested my code to build the dot diagram, when I tried to union two relations together and passed the the sumed up relation, following error is reported:

```
Expected rel[loc,loc] (...), but got rel[loc,loc]
```

I am not sure what relloc, loc means because each of the separated relations works correctly. Could please you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that message can be confusing!

- `rel[loc,loc] (...)` means a type of function which returns a `rel[loc,loc]` given some arguments `...` which are unspecified in this message
- `rel[loc,loc]` is just the type of a binary relation of `loc`

We sometimes see this kind of message occurring when `( )` brackets are used accidentally instead of `[ ]` for indexing into a relation. If you provide a little more context code, maybe we can diagnose the issue from that more precisely.